# Font-lock-keywords: highlighting multiple sub-expression

Tags: emacs, font-lock-mode

When setting up font-lock-keywords for a GNU/Emacs mode, is it possible to highlight multiple sub-expressions of a regular expression with a single matcher? What I'd like to do is something along the lines of:

```
("\\(foo\\)-\\(bar\\)" '(1 foo-face) '(2 bar-face))
```

What would be the correct syntax for something like that - or do I have to split it up into two distinct matchers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
("\\(foo\\)-\\(bar\\)" (1 foo-face) (2 bar-face))
```

(*i.e.* the same as yours but without the extra quotes).

I say this because I have various bits like this in my custom font-lock-keywords definitions.  Some of them have `nil t` on the end of the second one, like this:

```
("\\(foo\\)-\\(bar\\)" (1 foo-face) (2 bar-face nil t))
```

which correspond to the `OVERRIDE` and `LAXMATCH` optional flags and may be necessary depending on your precise circumstances.

The documentation for `font-lock-keywords` discusses this in some depth, although it's not always the simplest to follow -- I find it easier just to copy someone else's working setup, like the existing value of `c-font-lock-keywords-3`, for example.